# Creating a table in XSL:FO with upper and lower strips

Tags: xsl-fo

I need to create a table block in XSL: FO which should be divided vertically into  three portions i.e. 15% upper part, 70% middle part and 15% lower part. I am beginner in XSL.

Comment: I have created the block but it contains only side strip.

Answer (score 1):

You can **explicitly set the height of a table row** with the `height` attribute.

For example, here is a table with 3 rows and a single column; the first row is 15 mm high, the second one is 70 mm high and the third one is 15 mm high (I added a background color so that the row height is clearly visible in the output):

```
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
            <fo:table-column column-width="100%"/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row height="15mm" background-color="#AAFFFF">
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>cell 1</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row height="70mm" background-color="#FFAAFF">
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>cell 2</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row height="15mm" background-color="#FFFFAA">
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>cell 3</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

Note that if the requested row height is not sufficient to accommodate its contents, the formatter could choose to use the height of the content instead (*at least, this is how FOP behaves*); in other words, setting row height allows you to have **taller rows** than they would be  according to their contents, but **not shorter rows**.